# Generate new variables as functions of existing with foreach

Tags: loops, stata

I have searched the forum, but unfortunately cannot find the solution of my problem. I have 400 repeated measures for 30 study participants, and I want to generate the difference between the pairs of measurements for each participant. So I thought the `foreach` command would save me a lot of work.

The variable names have a prefix which lets me separate first and second measurement: `S_me` and `E_me`. This is followed by a 22 character long, specific code that allow me to pick the right measures:

So I want 1 new variable = the diff between `S_me_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1` and `E_me_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1`, 1 new variable for the diff between `S_me_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2` and `E_me_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2` up to  `S_me_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX400` and `E_me_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX400`

I have now tried:

```
unab where : S_me*
local where " `where'" 
local where : subinstr local where " S_me" " ", all 
display "`where'" 

foreach c of local where {
    gen Diff_`c' = S_me`c'- E_me`c' 
}
```

as I found a similar post here - but it does not work.

Neither does:

```
foreach x of varlist S_me* {
    gen Diff_`x' = (S_me`x'-E_me`x')
}
```

Now I hope someone sees a great solution to my problem.

Comment: Not the question, but repeated measures call for a long data layout, not a wide one. You are going to find it very difficult to do much with this set-up.

Comment: If you found any of the answers below helpful, then please consider accepting one by clicking on the check-mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of a `reshape` can be illustrated with a trimmed down version. You evidently have something like

```
clear 
input id S_me_X1 E_me_X1 S_me_X2 E_me_X2 
1    3 4 5 7    
2    10 12 14 16 
end
```

-- just different variable names and values and numbers of variables and values.

Once you `reshape` the difference is just one new variable:

```
reshape long S_me_ E_me_ , i(id) j(which) string 

gen diff = S_me - E_me 

list


     +-----------------------------------+
     | id   which   S_me_   E_me_   diff |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |  1      X1       3       4     -1 |
  2. |  1      X2       5       7     -2 |
  3. |  2      X1      10      12     -2 |
  4. |  2      X2      14      16     -2 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```

Once you get into the situation of creating 400 new variables every time you do something, you are sliding to perdition. How are you going to describe, graph, or model them?

Comment: I see that with my data the reshape option is indeed the way to go. I learnt a lot from you all!

Answer (score 1):

This captures all `S_me*` variables and generates 400 differences between this variable and the respective variable starting with `E`.

```
qui ds S_me_*
local x = 1
foreach v in `r(varlist)' {
    local str = substr("`v'",2,.)
    gen diff_`x' = `v' - E`str'
    local x = `x' + 1
}
```

EDIT Simpler as

```
local x = 1
foreach v of var S_me_*  {
    local str = substr("`v'",2,.)
    gen diff_`x' = `v' - E`str'
    local x = `x' + 1
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your post to show a simpler way to do it. `ds` is not needed here. Feel free to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

I think Nick's answer is by far the simplest, and you could `reshape` it back to `wide` afterwards to get to what I am doing here, but I'll show another way to do it in case you are using survey data with a baseline, as that appears to be what you are doing, and using a time series operator may be of value here, depending on what else you are doing with this data. Technically speaking, this is not the best solution for this problem in isolation. Note: I am doing this with 4 variables, instead of 400, for simplicity:

Data input:

```
* First, input data

clear
set obs 30
gen id = _n // Id for each participant
forvalues i = 1/4 {
    local first = "S_me_" + string(`i')
    gen `first' = runiform()
    local second = "E_me_" + string(`i')
    gen `second' = rnormal()
}
```

Now, you are essentially going to have a "pre" period dataset and a "post" period dataset, which we will append one on top of the other:

```
* Now, save E dataset separately, and append to bottom of S
preserve
    keep id E*
    * rename variables to common name
    forvalues i = 1/4 {
        rename E_me_`i' me`i'
    }
    tempfile E
    save `E'
restore

drop E*
* Rename variables to common name
forvalues i = 1/4 {
        rename S_me_`i' me`i'
    }

append using `E', gen(period)

* Set time series
tsset id period

* Generate first difference variable using ts operator "d."
foreach x of varlist me* {
    gen `x'_diff = d.`x'
}
```